# Iframe cross origin error in mobile when printing a blob pdf

Tags: web, iframe, mobile, printing, jspdf

I have a nextjs app that uses jsPDF to make pdf docs for printing or saving. When I want to print it I create an iframe, load blob uri inside and trigger print action,like showed in code bellow:

```
const handlePrintBlobPdf = (
  blobUrl: string
): Promise<HTMLIFrameElement | void> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

      document.body.appendChild(iframe);

      iframe.style.display = "none";
      iframe.src = blobUrl;

      iframe.contentWindow?.postMessage("print", "*");

      iframe.onload = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
          iframe.focus();

          iframe.contentWindow?.print();

          URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);

          resolve(iframe);
        }, 1);
      };
    } catch (error: any) {
      reject(error.message || "Error trying to print");
    }
  });
```

This approach works fine on desktops, literally no failures neither running local nor in production/dev, but when I try to do the same on mobile and use chrome devtools to debug, I get cross origin error: '**Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://my-website-url.com"**'

How to solve this? And there is a better aproach to make the same?

OBS.: I can't open it in another window to print, the print dialog must be shown inside the same page that user is, like when we press CTRL+P on browser.

I tried to print an PDF in blob format in browser in mobile devices (smartphones, tablets e etc) but it doesn't work because of iframe cross origin error. I expect to solve it